# flowplayer 3.2.5 version playlist clip not working in ie

Tags: javascript

I am using the flowplayer version 3.2.5 to stream video, I am using this code

```
flowplayer(divname, "flowplayer-3.2.5.swf", {  
    clip:{   
      onFinish:function() {
        s= parseInt(s) + parseInt(1);

        document.getElementById('loopinc'+val).value = s;
        var stpnote = document.getElementById('stopnote'+val).value;

          if(s == 3 && stpnote == "ON" && user != "M") {
            //alert(s + "  $ "+ val);
            document.getElementById('loopinc'+val).value = 1;    
            visibleme(val); 
          } else if(s == 3 && stpnote != "ON") {
            stopplayer(val);
          } 
      },
      onBeforeFinish: function () {
        // hide replay button
        this.getPlugin("play").css({opacity: 0});
      }
    },  

    playlist: [
      'Start.flv',
      { 
        url: 'buffer.gif',duration: 5, 
      },
      newfilename
    ],
});
```

this code working fine in Firefox but not in IE . if i remove the playlist clip

```
playlist: [
  'Start.flv',
  { 
    url: 'buffer.gif',duration: 5, 
  },
  newfilename
],
```

then run the code in IE then its working fine. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you getting any errors from IE? Which version are you using? Are you able to access IE's debug mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the last comma

```
playlist: [
  'Start.flv',
  { 
    url: 'buffer.gif',duration: 5, 
  },
  newfilename
],     <----- REMOVE THIS COMMA
```

Comment: first thank you for your reply, yes i removed that comma its working in mozilla , still i am facing the same problem in IE

Comment: It's propably just something very minor JS issue firefox is accepting and IE is not. Try removing the other comma after 5 (see my edit). It would help if you could answer the following: 1) Which version of IE are you using?, 2) Are you getting any errors?, 3) Are you able to access IE's debug mode?

Comment: 1 ) i am using IE6  2) i did not any error i get the empty block instead of the player 3) no

Comment: IE6, wow! That's impressive :) IE8 has nice debug mode for instance tracking IE JS errors. And of course Firebug for Firefox.